# WPF XAML pass to ConverterParameter array of enums

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums

I have enum

```
public enum DocumentTypes
{
    First, Second, Third, Fourth
}
```

How to pass values of `enum` to `<sys:Enum></sys:Enum>`

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Enums"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

       <Label Content="Test2">
            <Label.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                    <MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
                            <sys:Enum></sys:Enum>
                        </x:Array>
                    </MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                    <Binding ElementName="First" Path="IsChecked" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Second" Path="IsChecked" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Third" Path="IsChecked" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Fourth" Path="IsChecked" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Visibility>
        </Label>
```

Comment: The `IsChecked` property is a `bool`. Are you sure that's what you want to be passing into your converter?

Comment: @MikeEason, I know that isChecked is a bool. It's only examle. I don't know how to pass throug x:array enums.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do this :

```
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <local:DocumentTypes>First</local:DocumentTypes>
        <local:DocumentTypes>Second</local:DocumentTypes>
        <local:DocumentTypes>Third</local:DocumentTypes>
    </x:Array>
```

Comment: local namespace not found

Comment: use `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bindable Property to your datacontext like:

```
public IEnumerable DocumentTypesList
{
   get
   {
       return Enum.GetVaues(typeof(DocumentTypes));
   }
}
```

And bind to it via:

```
<MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
                    <Binding Path="DocumentTypesList">
</MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
```

This way, if your enum gets altered, you don´t have to change any XAML representation of it.

Or if the converter always uses this explicit enum, you could reference it directly in it.

Comment: You cannot Bind ConverterParameter.

Comment: My bad. Last time I handled those is a bit ago.
What you could do is, since you are already using a MultiValueConverter is either passing the enumerated enum  as an additional value or use
<x:Type Type="local:DocumentTypes" />
 and enumerate the enum in your converter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
  <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <x:Static Member="sys:Enum:YourEnumType.YourEnumValue1" />
    <x:Static Member="sys:Enum:YourEnumType.YourEnumValue2" />
  </x:Array>
</MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
```

In my project, I have added my enumeration type namespace like:

```
xmlns:mod="clr-namespace:MyProject.Modal;assembly=MyProject.Modal"
```

where MyProject.Modal is the namespace of my enumeration definition. In this way, if you have an enumeration names "MyEnum", then you could do this:

```
<MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
  <x:Array Type="{x:Type mod:MyEnum}">
    <x:Static Member="mod:MyEnum.Value1" />
    <x:Static Member="mod:MyEnum.Value2" />
  </x:Array>
</MultiBinding.ConverterParameter>
```

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9db5f1f5-f3a9-402c-9869-08d3624eea59/xarray-markup-extension-as-itemssource-for-combobox?forum=wpf